# ReactJS How to Show Answers from list when click on questions

Tags: reactjs

I've an array of questions and their answers. I need to show questions on the right and when user clicks on it, have to show answers along with the question on the left pane. How can I do this, here is my code so far:

```js
var list = [
  {
    title: "Title1 goes here",
    body: "Answer1 goes here"
  },
  {
    title: "Title2 goes here",
    body: "Answer2 goes here"
  },
  {
    title: "Title3 goes here",
    body: "Answer3 goes here"
  }
]

class Contact extends React.Component {
  handleClick(id, e) {
    alert(id)
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <div className="leftcol">
          <h2>FAQs</h2>
          <div className="faq-content" />
        </div>
        <div className="rightcol">
          <ul>
            {list.map((item, i) => (
              <li
                className="list-group-item"
                key={i}
                data-id={item.title}
                onClick={this.handleClick.bind(this, item.title)}
              >
                {item.title}
              </li>
            ))}
          </ul>
        </div>
      </div>
    )
  }
}
ReactDOM.render(<Contact />, document.getElementById("root"))
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```

Comment: Sharing a piece of code with what you have tried already could improve the chances of SO users to understand your problems and be able to help you.

Comment: As an aside, don't use `index` as your item `key`. If the list changes React will only know it's length changed, not what items changed and will likely render incorrectly. Ideally each item will have a unique id which you use as the key, otherwise you'll have to use the title.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### EDIT:

As per your requirement, I have simplified the answer.

```js
const list = [
  {
    title: " Question 1 - Title1 goes here",
    body: "Answer1 goes here"
  },
  {
    title: " Question 2 - Title2 goes here",
    body: " Question 3 - Answer2 goes here"
  },
  {
    title: "Title3 goes here",
    body: "Answer3 goes here"
  }
];

class Contact extends React.Component {
  state={
    selectedQuestion:'',
    correctAnswer:''
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <div className="leftcol">
          <h2>FAQs</h2>
          <div className="faq-content">
            <div style={{background:'orange'}}>
              <div style={{fontSize:30,fontWeight:'bold'}}>{this.state.selectedQuestion}</div>
              <div style={{fontSize:20}}>{this.state.correctAnswer}</div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div className="rightcol">
          <ul>
            {list.map((item, i) => (
              <li
                className="list-group-item"
                key={i}
                data-id={item.title}
                onClick={()=>this.setState({correctAnswer:item.body,selectedQuestion:item.title})}
              >
                {item.title}
              </li>
            ))}
          </ul>
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<Contact />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```

Comment: Thanks for the hint. This is right but I need to show the only selected question along with answer inside "<div className="faq-content">", how I can accomplish this ?

Comment: You can still use his example.  Throw the showAnswer in your component.  Then in your onclick handler throw it into showAnswer

Comment: Please check the edit, have simplified the solution.